# How to get text of a TextBox and send it from JavaScript to code-behind using QueryString

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, query-string

I know I'm asking 2 questions but I'm really stuck. I have a form for adding and updating records and when I click the Update button(my Add works fine with the pop-up), I want a pop-up to appear with the properties of the record I get from my script(i.e. every texbox/dropdownlist filled with the correct values).

This is my script:

```
function btnEditEP_Click() {
            var recID = document.getElementById('<%=tboxEdit.ClientID%>').textContent;
            //if (recID !=null) {
            //    alert("ok what now?");
            //}
            window.open("editPopupEP.aspx?Txt=" + recID, "_blank", "toolbar=yes", "resizable=yes", "scrollbars=yes");
        }
```

And this is my `PageLoad` in `editPopupEp.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                int recID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Txt="]);
                ...
                ..
                .
```

If I can get the record ID, populating the input fields is easy but I need/want to get the `Text` of the `Textbox` and receive it from codebehind with `QueryString`.

The pop-up window works and there are no errors but the `recID` has `0` in it and there is no such record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below line you are using textContent, it is not available in IE8 or below. Are you by any chance working on IE8?

```
var recID = document.getElementById('<%=tboxEdit.ClientID%>').textContent;
```

You can try something like this otherwise:

```
var recID =  document.getElementById('<%=tboxEdit.ClientID%>').value;
```

In your page_load event, you can use the below code:

```
int recID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Txt"]);
```

Use above code if textbox will always have integer value otherwise use below code.

```
int recID;
if(Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["Txt"], out recID))
{
 //Do whatever you want to do with recID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to omit the equal sign when accessing the QueryString collection, like this:

```
Request.QueryString["Txt"]
```

Comment: I get this error when I do that `{"Input string was not in a correct format."}`

Comment: This probably means that the conversion with Convert.ToInt32 failed because the input is not a valid string (probably because it's null). This would mean that there is no "Txt" QueryString present. Have you tried to set a breakpoint and check the contents of `Request.QueryString`?

Comment: It appears to be `{Txt=}`. I removed the equal sign from `Request.QueryString` though.

Comment: I think this means that the query parameter `Txt` is present, but without value. If it would have a value, it would look like this: `{Txt=1234}` So this makes me believe you are not setting the Txt query param in your JS correctly. What's the value of `recID`?

Comment: Also, you could always try to manually open the `editPopupEP.aspx` page and pass it a hard-coded record ID. This would help you figure out if you have a problem in your JS or in your code-behind.

Comment: Ok now we know there is something wrong with my JS. Manually passing the record ID worked fine.